# Junit testing methods with simulating user inputs

Tags: java, junit, java.util.scanner

Problem description: I need to test methods which require user input with Scanner object. My current approach to simulate user inputs:

`String input = String.join(System.lineSeparator(), "2", "COUNTRY", "ENGLAND", "n");
    System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes()));`

works fine, but only in case I run those tests independenly (one by one). There's a problem, when I try to run all the tests in a row - there's an exception

**org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception thrown: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found**

My current approach (2 tests out of 3 are shown - only the one - the first passes due to the mentioned problem)

```
 @Test
  @DisplayName("update shop with valid arguments should not throw an exception. Updated Country should be properly set")
  void test8() {

    //given
    String input = String.join(System.lineSeparator(), "2", "COUNTRY", "ENGLAND", "n");
    System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes()));

    Shop shop = Shop.builder()
            .name("SHOP")
            .country(Country.builder()
                    .name("CHINA")
                    .build())
            .build();

    ArgumentCaptor<Shop> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Shop.class);

    given(shopRepository.findById(argThat(num -> num == Long.parseLong(input.split("[\\s]")[0]))))
            .willReturn(Optional.of(
                    shop
            ));


    //when
    //then
    assertDoesNotThrow(shopService::updateShop);

    then(shopRepository).should(times(1)).addOrUpdate(argumentCaptor.capture());

    assertAll("Updated shop properties should be changed, not updated ones should remain constant",
            () -> assertThat(argumentCaptor.getValue().getName(), is(equalTo("SHOP"))),
            () -> assertThat(argumentCaptor.getValue().getCountry().getName(), is(equalTo("ENGLAND")))
    );


  }

  @Test
  @DisplayName("Update shop with valid arguments should not throw an exception. Updated Country and Shop Name should be properly set")
  void test9() {

    //given
    String input = String.join(System.lineSeparator(), "7", "COUNTRY", "GERMANY", "y", "NAME", "BB", "n");
    System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes()));

    Shop shop = Shop.builder()
            .name("AA")
            .country(Country.builder()
                    .name("FRANCE")
                    .build())
            .build();

    ArgumentCaptor<Shop> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Shop.class);

    given(shopRepository.findById(argThat(num -> num == Long.parseLong(input.split("[\\s]")[0]))))
            .willReturn(Optional.of(
                    shop
            ));


    //when
    //then
    assertDoesNotThrow(shopService::updateShop);

    then(shopRepository).should(times(1)).addOrUpdate(argumentCaptor.capture());

    assertAll("Updated shop properties - country and name should be changed",
            () -> assertThat(argumentCaptor.getValue().getName(), is(equalTo("BB"))),
            () -> assertThat(argumentCaptor.getValue().getCountry().getName(), is(equalTo("GERMANY")))
    );


  }
```

I suppose it's because there's no new line found for Scanner, the thing is I'm not sure how to solve, so the tests could be run in a row, not just one by one.

Comment: Just a quick note: `System.lineSeparator()` means your test will run differently on different systems.  I'd prefer to see one test for `LF` and one test for `CRLF` so that both can be tested explicitly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. When you use `System.setIn()` you most likely need to "clean up" your test method to get back to the original state like it didn't run.

Comment: And I hadn't read that far but `setIn()` is a terrible idea in all circumstances.

Comment: @Progman That's what I was thinking, not sure how to "reset" it though.
@markspace what do you suggest instead of using  `setIn()`

Comment: Can you separate your program so that the scanner is not nested so deeply inside some of the other components? When you're testing with `setIn()` you're basically testing the Scanner object which you can probably assume works already. If you must use data read in as separate commands, could you pass in an array of Strings instead?

Comment: I suggest what Nicko just said:  use dependency injection.  Inject a `Reader` into the class and wrap the `Scanner` around that..  In test, inject a `StringReader` with test data.  At runtime, inject a `Reader` wrapped around `System.in`.

Comment: @markspace Ok, it seems that's a good way round the problem. Thx